# null pointer error

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I a have login window in my application, where a method which pulls out password from database and then puts into `arraylist1`. Also passwords put in by user are put into an `arraylist2` and then I check if `arraylist1` contains `arraylist2` and if yes,then they can proceed if not, then system prints a message that password is wrong. Unfortunately I keep getting `null pointer error`

Please check my code:

`Model.java`

```
public class Model {

       public ArrayList<LogPass> getPass() throws SQLException{

        Connection con =null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        ArrayList<LogPass> list = new ArrayList<LogPass>();
        try{
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxxx?user=bbbbb&password=aaaaaa");
        stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT Pass FROM Logpass");
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
        LogPass t = new LogPass();
        t.setPass(rs.getString("Pass"));
        list.add(t);
        }
        }
        finally{ 
                if(rs != null) try {rs.close();}catch (SQLException se){}
                if (stmt != null) try{stmt.close();} catch (SQLException se){}
                if (con != null) try {con.close();}catch (SQLException se){}


        }

            return list;

        }

    }
```

`Login.java`

```
public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Control c = new Control();
Model m;

    /**
     * Creates new form Login
     */
    public Login() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jComboBox1.setMaximumRowCount(2);
        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Staff", "Manager", " " }));

        jLabel1.setText("Username");

        jLabel2.setText("Password");

        jLabel3.setText("Domain");

        jButton1.setText("Login");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Exit");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(62, 62, 62)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                        .addComponent(jButton2))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1))
                        .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addComponent(jPasswordField1)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1)
                            .addComponent(jComboBox1, 0, 120, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                .addContainerGap(103, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jPanel1Layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {jLabel1, jLabel2, jLabel3});

        jPanel1Layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {jButton1, jButton2});

        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(42, 42, 42)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 41, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jButton2)
                            .addComponent(jButton1))
                        .addGap(29, 29, 29))))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        //try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            //String a = new String(jPasswordField1.getPassword());
           // ArrayList<LoginPass2> list2 = new ArrayList<LoginPass2>();
            //LoginPass2 l = new LoginPass2();
            //l.setPass2(a);
            //list2.add(l);

            //if(m.getPass().equals(l)){
           // if(m.getPass().containsAll(list2)){
           this.setVisible(false);
           c.setVisible(true);
        //}//else{System.out.println("Wrong username or password!");}
        //} catch (SQLException ex) {
           // Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        //}

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new Login().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

`LogPass.java`

```
public class LogPass {
        private String log;
        private String pass;


        public String getLog(){
        return log;
        }
       public void setLog(String l){
            log = l ;


        }
        public String getPass(){
        return pass;
        }
        public void setPass(String p){
            pass = p ;


        }

    }
```

`LoginPass2.java`

```
    public class LoginPass2 {
        private String log;
        private String pass;


        public String getLog2(){
        return log;
        }
        public void setLog2(String l){
            log = l ;


        }
        public String getPass2(){
        return pass;
        }
        public void setPass2(String p){
            pass = p ;


        }

    }
```

and this is the error message i get

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at fish.Login.jButton1ActionPerformed(Login.java:152)
    at fish.Login.access$000(Login.java:14)
    at fish.Login$1.actionPerformed(Login.java:59)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

thanks for your help:)

Comment: Where is line 152 of Login.java?

Comment: Lol, there was indeed a stack trace dug deep beneath the codes.

Comment: just write catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

Comment: What is `m` in `m.getPass()`?

Comment: What's this? `c.setVisible(true);` I can't see any `c` variable in the code

Comment: you have m and c declared at the in class Login also this is line 152 class Login: if(m.getPass().containsAll(list2))   sorry i'm very new to coding as u probably can see :P

Comment: @novice There is no Login class. Only the contructor... Add the whole code and please separate those classes so we can see it better. And format the code...

Answer (score 1):

Where are you getting the NULL pointer error?

You should error check for the variables `con` , `stmt` and `rs` after their assignments. Also , your `while` loop seems to be wrong. First, it does not seem to be moving through the set. Also, are you sure the condition returns `true`?

Comment: i get null pointer after i put in a password and press the button

Answer (score 0):

In jButton1ActionPerformed method u are using undefined "m" variable.

Comment: this is the beginning of my class Login:                         public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    
Control c = new Control();
Model m;

Comment: yes, but u are never initialize that var. Or i cannt found this =/

Answer (score 0):

I think that you forgot to initialize member variables in `Login` class. I can't see any `m` or `c` variables to be initialized in the constructor.

But you have to post the whole code to see this properly. And mark the line where you get the NPE. Saying it's the line 152 realy doesn't help anyone...